# Why using static methods is recommended in Effective Java?

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection

I'm looking at chapter 1 of *Effective Java(3th ed, Joshua J. Bloch)*

and It says using a static method is better than constructor.

But I understand that **static** is loaded in memory when classloader initiates,

and in normal case the static members are not removed by garbage collector

until the class unloaded.

So if I understood right, when I use more and more classes which have static method,

It consumes more memory, am I right?

Is that memory timid to concern, or there are other reasons to use them nevertheless?

Comment: All methods, whether static or not, as well as constructors, are part of the class and will require memory when the class is loaded. Which you use, has no impact on the memory.

Comment: That book is great. Everyone who writes Java should read that cover to cover (more than once!). Related to this question: read Item 55 – Optimize Judiciously. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static **member variables** are not garbage collected (assuming the classloader is still alive), since the class itself will always hold a reference to it. The same is not true of **methods**.

Static methods (a.k.a factory methods) are sometimes preferred for a few reasons.

- You can name them how you want: Imagine the following constructor: `public Hyperlink(String string){...}`. It is not clear what the string actually refers to. Is it the text to be made into the link? Is it the URL? Imagine instead the static factory `public Hyperlink.fromURL(String string){...}`. Much clearer.
- Caching - the `new` keyword **always** creates a new object, or it throws an exception. There is no way to return an object that already exists in a cache somewhere. With a static factory, you could first check that the object does not already exist, and retrieve it if it does, and call a constructor if it doesn't.
- Polymorphism - Consider the classes `Animal` and `Dog extends Animal`. The constructor `public Animal(String species){...}` always returns an `Animal` object. `Dog dog = Animal.fromSpecies(String species);` however, is valid.

There are of course reasons to use constructors, but personally, I will always go for a static factory method for anything vaguely complex.

Concerning memory usage, the cost of storing methods, except in **very** large projects or **very** constrained systems is negligible. Load time is another issue, but not one that is improved by avoiding static methods.

Comment: So can static **methods** garbage be collected while it has been processing by class?

Comment: Methods are not garbage collected at all. They are loaded when the class is loaded and unloaded when the class is unloaded. They take a constant amount of memory while the program is executed. Only **objects** are GC'ed. Remember, premature optimisation is evil. Write your code in a sensible, readable way, and if you notice real performance issues, optimise later.

Comment: You are correct in thinking that, for example, a very large static List would potentially lead to memory issues, but the same does not apply to methods.